# What tool can I use to measure the volume of .mp3 on my S6 + make the volume all the same?

Tags: mp3

I have powerAmp paid and I have mp3's from different sources. How do I measure the decibel levels of each clip + adjust it to make it the same? I used to use Mp3gain on the desktop. Anything like that for Android on and S6?

Answer (score 0):

PowerAmp can read ReplayGain values written to the mp3 files, but does not do any analysis itself.  The best option would be to apply ReplayGain tags using something like [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) on your desktop, and then copy those files over to your S6.